# Autoscaling workers on Laravel

Tags: laravel

how do you handle autoscaling of workers?

Right now I am using laravel forge, which is very good, but we're scaling our saas and I am looking for solution to not have all workers up and running especially if I dont need them. and sometimes we need more workers in the busiest times than we have set up.
What is the best solution to use some kind of autoscale and start and stop laravel workers on demand? I found Vapor, but I am pretty scared to use AWS due to unexpected cost, overcharges etc. Its common problem with AWS, I know a lot of ppl who got thousands of $ per month bills for just one click mistake etc. So I would love to stay with Forge.

I have around 4,5-5M requests per day +-.

thanks a lot for your help

Comment: When you refer to workers do you mean Laravel queue workers? I ask because you mentioned request per day, but I am not sure how this relates to queue workers. You can have a lot of rps but very few queued jobs or vice versa.

Comment: Or do you mean you have to process around 5 million jobs on the queue workers per day?